# ¿Porqué me da error cuando elimino un registro y éste tiene elementos vinculados?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Tengo un pequeño CRUD usando Entity Framework, la base está diseñada con dos tablas, una de Personas y la otra de números de Teléfono.

El problema es que cuando trato de eliminar una persona que tiene números de teléfono asignados no se elimina la persona, solamente los números de teléfono.

Además de eso se detiene la ejecución del programa en la línea que dice `cnx.SaveChanges()` de la función `EliminarPersona` lanzando el mensaje de error:

> The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.

El código es el siguiente:

```
    public void EliminarPersona(int id)
    {
        using (AgendaEntities cnx = new AgendaEntities())
        {
            var persona = cnx.Persona.Single(p => p.Id == id);
            if (persona.Telefono.Count > 0) // Si la persona tiene números de teléfono se deben eliminar
                EliminarTelefonos(persona.Id);
            cnx.Persona.Remove(persona);
            cnx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public void EliminarTelefonos(int idPersona)
    {
        try
        {
            using (AgendaEntities cnx = new AgendaEntities())
            {
                var tels = cnx.Telefono.Where(t => t.IdPersona == idPersona);
                cnx.Telefono.RemoveRange(tels);
                cnx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
```

Cabe destacar que anteriormente estuve usando la función `Remove()` para eliminar cada número de teléfono (los recorría con un bucle) y también me daba error en la función `SaveChanges()`, esta vez de la función `EliminarTelefonos`.

Espero me puedan ayudar, y les agradezco de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tu problema puede derivar del hecho que estás instanciando dos contextos diferentes, y al momento de eliminar el contexto en el método EliminarPersona no lleva registro de los cambios realizados en el contexto que tienes en el método EliminarTelefonos, por tanto no tiene los cambios reflejados de la eliminación de los teléfonos. Prueba con el siguiente código:

```
public void EliminarPersona(int id)
{
    using (AgendaEntities cnx = new AgendaEntities())
    {
        var persona = cnx.Persona.Single(p => p.Id == id);
        if (persona.Telefono.Count > 0) // Si la persona tiene números de teléfono se deben eliminar
            EliminarTelefonos(persona.Id);

        cnx.Entry(persona).Reload(); // Carga los últimos cambios que se hallan hecho en base de datos
        cnx.Persona.Remove(persona);
        cnx.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public void EliminarTelefonos(int idPersona)
{
    try
    {
        using (AgendaEntities cnx = new AgendaEntities())
        {
            var tels = cnx.Telefono.Where(t => t.IdPersona == idPersona);
            cnx.Telefono.RemoveRange(tels);
            cnx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

Sin embargo, te recomiendo hacer todo en una sola transacción y NO usar dos contextos, esto debido a que si ocurre algún error podrías terminar eliminando únicamente los teléfonos sin eliminar a la persona. En resumen, utiliza un solo contexto, aqui te doy un ejemplo de como quedaría mas optimizado (a mi parecer) tu código:

```
public void EliminarPersona(int id)
{
    using (AgendaEntities cnx = new AgendaEntities())
    {
        var persona = cnx.Persona.Single(p => p.Id == id);
        if (persona.Telefono.Count > 0) 
        {
           var tels = cnx.Telefono.Where(t => t.IdPersona == persona.Id);
           cnx.Telefono.RemoveRange(tels);
        }

        cnx.Persona.Remove(persona);
        cnx.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Espero de sea de utilidad. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias amigo, de la primer manera que me dijiste no funcionó, pero al ponerlo todo en una misma función funcionó correctamente.